# SignalR self host throw NullReferenceException on WebApp.start

Tags: c#, signalr

Im using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost with Console project net6.0 on windows.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Server.Startup))]
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080");

        {
            Console.WriteLine("started: " + url);
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<test>();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And it gives me NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080");

Comment: [How to have a Self Hosting signalR server running as as NetCore Console App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68098114/7687666)